# Inserting a new node in a singly-linked list while maintaining the sorting

Tags: c++, list, sorting, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm very much a noob and I'm struggling to correctly implement the insertion of a new node in a singly-linked list. I've tried some of the more easy-to-understand solutions from both here and other sites and the problem is definitely in my brain, but I just can't manage to get this right.

So what I have is this linked list made up of n nodes (where n is given as an input by the user) where I'm trying to insert randomised numbers from 0 to 100 in increasing order and I'm then printing the content of the list.

I think my code is not quite right at all though because the output I get is just the same number over and over, but besides that if I change the code to allow the user to input the numbers instead of generating them randomly, the program crashes if I input two different numbers (it works ok if I input the same number over and over). EDIT: Furthermore, unless srand(time(NULL)); is written inside a loop, the program will compile but crash once I input the amount of elements in my list.

I really can't understand what I'm doing wrong though.

The code looks like this:

```
/*The program inserts n elements generated randomly in a linked list sorted increasingly, and prints the result.*/

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    int num;
    node *next;
};
node *top=NULL,*nodenew;

void sortedinsert();
void printlist();

int main() {
    int n;
    do {
        cout<<"Insert the amount of elements in your list: ";
        cin>>n;
        if (n<2) {
            cout<<"The list needs to contain at least 2 nodes."<<endl;
        }
    }
    while (n<2);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        srand(time(NULL));
        sortedinsert();
    }
    printlist();
}

void sortedinsert() {
    int gen=rand()%101;
    nodenew=new node;
    nodenew->num=gen;
    nodenew->next=NULL;
    if (top==NULL or top->num>=gen) {
        nodenew->next=top;
        top=nodenew;
        return;
    }
    else if (top->next!=NULL and top->next->num>=gen){
        node *temp=top->next;
        nodenew->next=temp;
        top->next=nodenew;
        return;
    }
    else {
        node *left;
        node *right=top;
        while (right!=NULL and right->next->num<=gen) {
            left=right;
            right=right->next;
        }
        left->next=nodenew;
        nodenew->next=right;
    }
}
void printlist() {
    cout<<"The sorted list is shown below: "<<endl;
    for (nodenew=top;nodenew!=NULL;nodenew=nodenew->next) {
        cout<<nodenew->num<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: side note : srand(time(NULL)); this initialization  should be at the beginning of your program not inside some loop

Comment: Side note: this line `while (n<2);` is an infinite loop if the condition is met

Comment: @Spinkoo ah yes, I forgot to mention that unless I put srand(time(NULL)); in a loop the program crashes, that incldues putting srand right after int main() {, which makes me think my code has a few others underlying problems I might not be seeing

Comment: @KWierzbicki it's part of the do while that checks whether the user has inserted more than or equal to 2 elements in the list, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Matt17BR Oh, yes you're totally right, the formating misled me

Comment: The best way to navigate a linked list assignment is to draw a lot of pictures to help you visualize the problem. Once you have pictures that make sense to use as a baseline, execute your code on paper instruction by instruction to attempt to draw the same list. If you can't, you found a bug and since you have a picture of what you should have drawn, you probably stopped yourself as soon as you started drawing the wrong thing and know where the bug is and what you need to do instead. Victory is likely yours at that point.

Comment: If not, drop your program into the debugger that should have come with your development environment. If you don't have a debugger, claw your way up into the 1980s and get a development environment with a debugger. With the debugger you can control the execution of your program, advancing instruction by instruction if you have to. When the program does something unexpected, you just found a bug. Inspect the variables involved to see why it happened. Backtrack if you have to to find out why any variables were wrong.

Comment: @user4581301 that's a couple of great tips, I've actually tried drawing similar programs with pen and paper before but I find I just lose focus at some point. Guess I should just try harder if I get stuck again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've commented the parts i changed :)

```
int main() {
    int n; // as mentioned in top srand initialized at the begining 
    srand(time(NULL));

    do {
        cout << "Insert the amount of elements in your list: ";
        cin >> n;
        if (n < 2) {
            cout << "The list needs to contain at least 2 nodes." << endl;
        }
    } while (n < 2);
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        sortedinsert();
    }
    printlist();
}

void sortedinsert() {
    int gen = rand() % 101;
    nodenew = new node;
    nodenew->num = gen;
    nodenew->next = NULL;
    // split the top part
    if (top == NULL) {

        top = nodenew;
        return;
    }
    if( top->num >= gen) {
        nodenew->next = top;
        top = nodenew;
        return;
    }

    else if (top->next != NULL and top->next->num >= gen) {
        node *temp = top->next;
        nodenew->next = temp;
        top->next = nodenew;
        return;
    }
    else {
        // left was uninitialized so if it doesn't go into the loop you are going to call left->next  Undefined behavior
       //right->next->num<=gen you don't test this until you test right->next is not null otherwise Undefined behavior as well
        node *left=top;
        node *right = top->next;

        while (right != NULL and right->num <= gen) {
            left = right;
            right = right->next;
        }       


            left->next = nodenew;
            nodenew->next = right;


    }
}
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough, that truly helps me understand what I wasn't doing correctly!

Answer (score 0):

In fact srand(time(NULL)) you must declare it before for loop because like that it gives the same number .
And you have a problem when inserting a newnode .

And here i have corrected your code and it works well :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    int num;
    node *next;
};
node *top = NULL, *nodenew;

void sortedinsert();
void printlist();

int main() {
    int n;

    do {
        cout << "Insert the amount of elements in your list: ";
        cin >> n;
        if (n<2) {
            cout << "The list needs to contain at least 2 nodes." << endl;
        }
    } while (n<2);

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {


        sortedinsert();
    }
    printlist();

    system("pause");
}

void sortedinsert() {


    int gen = rand() % 101;
    cout << gen << endl;
    nodenew = new node;
    nodenew->num = gen;
    nodenew->next = NULL;
    if (top == NULL || top->num >= gen) {
        nodenew->next = top;
        top = nodenew;

    }
    else
    {
        node *A = top;
        node *B = top->next;
        while (B != NULL)
        {
            if (B->num > gen)
            {
                nodenew->next = B;
                A->next = nodenew;
                return;
            }
            else
            {

                A = B;
                B = B->next;
            }
        }
        A->next = nodenew;
        nodenew->next = NULL;
        return;
    }
}
void printlist() {
    cout << "The sorted list is shown below: " << endl;
    nodenew = top;

    for (nodenew = top; nodenew != NULL; nodenew = nodenew->next) {
        cout << nodenew->num << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Python code as shown below . The benefits you will have with Python is :

--> It is now used in many industries , and will help you when you explore the regions of Data Science and Machine Learning.

--> It is as easy as implementing pseudocode .

I have shown you the python method for inserting a node into a sorted Doubly linked list , try to get Dry-Run the code and obtain the logic , then use the same to derive code for Singly Linked list .

```
def sortedInsert(head, data):
node = DoublyLinkedListNode(data)
status = 0
if not data>head.data:
    node.prev=head.prev
    head.prev=node
    node.next=head
    head=node
else:
    dup = head
    while(data>dup.data):
        if not dup.next:
            status = 1
            break
        else:
            dup = dup.next
    if status:
        node.prev = dup
        node.next = dup.next
        dup.next = node
    else:
        node.prev = dup.prev
        dup.prev.next = node
        node.next = dup
        dup.prev = node
return head
```

Comment: The question being asked is written in C++, it would be reasonable to assume (as there is no indication otherwise) that this needs to be done in C++. Answering in Python is not helpful in this situation.